# How can I get the current logged in gmail user from cloud end point?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to get the current email id of the logged in google user. I tried something like the following which works in dev mode but not in production mode.

```
public class EndpointAPI {

@ApiMethod(httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, path = "getuser")
public Container getLoggedInUser() {

    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User guser = userService.getCurrentUser();

    Container container = new Container();
    container.user = "user not logged in";

    if (null != guser)
        container.user = guser.getEmail();

    return container;
}

public class Container {
    public String user;
}   
}
```

I tried looking at the documentation (and tried adding client ids, scope etc) but could not successfully find what I need to do.

If someone can post a simple working example it will be much appreciated.

Regards,
Sathya

Comment: When you say something "does not work", you need to be more specific. What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At simplest, you should register a client ID for a web application, and request a `User` object within the method signature of your API call. Example that supports requests from the JS client:

Ids.java:

```
public class Ids {
  public static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com";
}
```

MyEndpoint.java:

```
@Api(clientIds = {Ids.WEB_CLIENT_ID})
public class MyEndpoint {
  public getFoo(User user) throws OAuthRequestException {
    if (user != null) {
      // do something with user
    } else {
      throw new OAuthRequestException("Invalid user.");
    }
  }
}
```

`user` will automatically be populated with the current user represented by the token passed to your API, or `null` in the case of an invalid or missing token. The example above throws an exception when there isn't a valid user object, but you can also choose to allow unauthenticated access.

Check out the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth) for more.